# How to use Chrome Copresence API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is a basic question, but I am new to JavaScript, and I want to use some Chrome APIs. My problem lies in understanding what the page is trying to tell me, for instance, what do they mean by types on this [page](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/copresence)? How would I create a message using the details on that page for a message? I apologize if it seems like a newb question, but I am new to this and am completely lost.

Basically I am trying to better understand what is meant by type. Does that mean I have to create variables that satisfy the parameters of that type? SO for the [execute](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/copresence#method-execute) method, I would pass it a variable that satisfies the type of a message? Thanks!

```
var message = ("type","payload");
chrome.copresence.execute([message], function callback)
```

Comment: You have picked a weird example - that API is experimental and not generally available. Do you need help with it specifically? I can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

Untested due to the lack of a supported device:

```
chrome.copresence.execute([
    {
        publish: {
            id: "someID",
            message: {type: "joke", payload: data},
            timeToLiveMillis: 1000,
            policy: {onlyEarshot: true}
        }
    }
], function(status) {
    console.log(status);
});
```

`payload` is an ArrayBuffer per documentation, so to send a string you'd have to convert it (I guess) like this, for example:

```
var data = new TextEncoder("utf8").encode("Hello, world!").buffer;
```